# Error 224003 (JWPLAYER) en webview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, jwplayer

Hola buenas estoy intentando reproducir un video desde el WEBVIEW con el reproductor JWPLAYER, pero este me da el error `224003`. He buscado por internet y no he encontrado nada.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la configuración del WEBVIEW que utilizo:

```
    WebSettings webSettings = player.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    player.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    final WebChromeClient webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient();

    player.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
```

**EDIT**
Aquí esta la [URL](https://mhdflix.ml/embed.php?v=https://m.vk.com/doc692876976_629644363?hash=5ceefe5d803058d959&dl=ca76da27e7761e0974) de prueba:

Comment: y sin usar un WebView funciona sin problema? , cual es la url del video?

Comment: A que se refiere, sin usar WebView ?, se refiere a usarlo con otras navegadores, entonces si funciona. El url del video ya se ha añadido en la pregunta.

Comment: A mi ese video no se me carga ni se me reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema indica que no puede reproducir el recurso ya que no existe o el video no esta soportado por el navegador, en este caso incluso se indica en la documentación de JWPlayer

> [`224003` No se pudo reproducir el recurso asociado porque no es
> compatible con este navegador. Equivalente el error HTML5:
> `MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED`](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-player-errors-reference)

Existen varias causas para este error, pero en este caso [el player no puede reproducir el video tampoco desde en un navegador](https://mhdflix.ml/embed.php?v=https://m.vk.com/doc692876976_629644363?hash=5ceefe5d803058d959&dl=ca76da27e7761e0974):

**la razón es que el recurso que trata de reproducir (https://m.vk.com/doc692876976_629644363?hash=5ceefe5d803058d959.mp4) simplemente no existe**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      jwplayer("player").setup({
       file: "https://m.vk.com/doc692876976_629644363?hash=5ceefe5d803058d959.mp4",
       image: "",
       width: "12:5",
       height: "500",
       stretching: "exactfit",
      });
     </script>
```

Comment: gracias, ya he podido darle solución. Pero es extraño porque a mi si me cargaban los videos pero desde el modo incognito no, me salía ese error (224003), ahora mismo he puesto el `<video>` y esta funcionando correctamente.

Comment: Si, veo que el .mp4 ya existe ahora si se puede reproducir!, saludos